# Variável não parece como declarada

Tags: xcode

Duas questões:

1. Não entendo qual é a razão a cada final de texto parece um `\n`.
2. Declarei uma variável `name`, e quando chamo a variável no meio do texto não parece que não foi declarada.

Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Código:

```
import UIKit

var age = 19

if age >= 18 {
    print("You can play")
} else {
    print("sorry are young")
}

var name = "Lucas"

if name == "Lucas" {
    print("Hi, + name + welcome")
}
```

Print da tela:

[image: Print de Tela]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu `name` não está como variável e sim como *String*, deve ficar assim:

```
print(" Hi, "+name+" welcome")
```

O `\n` no texto é por que você está usando o comando `print`,
este comando imprime um código para uma nova linha ao final.
para que isso não aconteça você deve fazer assim:

```
print(" Hi, "+name+" welcome", terminator: "")
```

Comment: Obrigado Jasar Orion, funcionou porem o \n ainda aparece

Comment: mesmo usando o terminator?

print("You can play", terminator: "")

Comment: Agora deu, tinha um espaço a mais. Thanks

Comment: rsss otimo ^^ 
marca resposta como resolvido ai e ja era

Comment: mais uma pergunta onde fecho onde mudo pra resolvido acabei de criar a conta

Comment: ta vendo no meu comentário ontem tem o numero um com uma seta para cima e para baixo ? logo abaixo tem um V. É só da um check

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro você use um método chamado *String Interpolation* que possibilita você usar qualquer tipo que conforme ao protocolo `CustomStringConvertible` (*String, Double, Int*, etc).

Para inserir a sua variável dentro da *String* basta colocar a variável entre parênteses e precedida de contra-barra `\(suaVariavel)`.

No seu caso ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
print("Hi, \(name) welcome")
```